# DateTime as class generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way in C# to add a class constraint that simply makes sure that the `type` is either `DateTime` or `Nullable<DateTime>`? Or makes sure that they have an `== operator` that is compatible with `DateTime`?

Below is a simplified use case where I have a method which I try to re-use between two entitites. In reality it is reused between four different entitites. The all share a "similiar" interface but some have a `DateTime?` and others have `DateTime` for their `Created`-property.

I really just need to make sure that they can compare with a specific `DateTime` which is fetched by another method `GetDateForLastMonth()`.

Limitations for this is that I *cannot* change the properties for the entities. Although, I can add new interfaces for them. I cannot change the returned `type` from `GetDateForLastMonth`.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<OrderEntity> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceEntity> Invoices { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsForSomePeriod<T, TDateType>(DbSet<T> dbSet) 
        where T : class, IHaveACreationDate<TDateType> 
        where TDateType : DateTime // Does not compile because "Only class or interface could be specified as constraint"
    {
        DateTime someDate = GetSomeDate();
        DateTime someOtherDate = GetSomeOtherDate();
        DateTime someThirdDate = GetAThirdDate();
        return dbSet
            .Where(x => (x.Created == lastMonth || x.Created == someOtherDate ||  x.Create == someThirdDate)) // Cannot compare because Created and someDate isn't same Type
            .ToArray();
    }
}

public interface IHaveACreationDate<T>
{
    T Created { get;}
}

public class OrderEntity: IHaveACreationDate<DateTime?>
{
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

}

public class InvoiceEntity : IHaveACreationDate<DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A better question would be why make `GetItemsForLastMonth` generic? Even more important, why work on an arbitrary `DbSet` when what you really need is an expression for the `Where` clause? You could create an extension method on IQueryable<T> if you wanted, assuming all T's implemented the same interface that provides `Created`,eg `IQueryable<T> ForLastMonth<T>(IQueryable<T> query)=>query.Where(x=>x.Created==lastMonth)`

Comment: what is so **generic** about a function that works only for two very **specific** types? No, generics are the completely whrong thing here. Just write two overloads, one for `DateTime`, one for `DateTime?`.

Comment: The problem is, the compiler has to select a *single* `==` operator to generate a call to. And, being the compiler, obviously it has to do this at *compile* time. There's no specialization based on concrete types.

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of "repository" on top of the DbSet repository?

Comment: EF Core would have no problem with `Created`, whether it's a DateTime or a DateTime? anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere; as I mentioned in the question it's really four different types (with other specifics), which would create 4 different overloads. That would work fine, but would create more code to maintain where most of the logic is 100% repetetive.

Comment: yeah, but the point is that `DateTime` and `DateTime?` don´t have **anything** in common. They are completely different types, so generics simply don´t apply here. Things are getting even worse, if you consider more types, e.g. `int` or even `double`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I agree that they are quite different. But for my scenario `DateTime` and `DateTime?` share the only thing that is interesting; EF can compare them both with eachother without any explicit casting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Very true indeed. A `where`-clause could indeed work better. My problem (which is not mentioned in the question) is that the where clause itself has 3 different DateTimes and I want all items where at least one of them are equal. (I'll update the question).

Comment: @smoksnes `.Where().Where().Where()` works and essentially creates an `AND` clause. If you wanted `OR` you could use `||` in the expression

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *Are you trying to create some kind of "repository" on top of the DbSet repository?* - Not really. It's just an example.